# select only data that must exist on two tables and returning single row only

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have two tables, students table and student_subject.  i want to pick students whose student_id appeared on student_subject table, and i want to return only single row.

Table students

|student_id |name
|1                         |John
|2                        |James

Table subjects

id |subject_id  | student_id  | subject_name 
1  |  2                     |1                             |Mathematics 
2  |  1                       |1                            |English 
3  |  3                    |1                            |Biology

my code

```
$this->db->select('*')
        ->from('students')
        ->where('student_id IN (select student_id from student_subject'));
```

i want to display only single row like this:-
|student_id |name
|1                         |John

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select *
from students s
where exists (
        select 1
        from subjects j
        where s.student_id = j.student_id
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use query as below:

```
$this->db->select('students.student_id, students.name')
    ->from('students')
    ->join('subjects', 'students.id = subjects.student_id')
    ->group_by('students.id');
```

Comment: it will return whole columns from both table

Answer (score 0):

try this.using join

```
$this->db->select('students.student_id as sid,students.name as sname',false);
$this->db->from('students s1');
$this->db->join('subjects s2','s1.student_id = s2.student_id');
$this->db->groupby('s1.student_id');
```

access using alias name like

$row->sid,$row->sname

**note:-** group_by() was formerly known as groupby(), which has been removed.